# Tamper with post data before it is sent

Tags: penetration-test, http

I am currently doing some pentesting for my work (not my job role but i always wanted to learn). I am trying to modify post and get data as it is sent (intercept, tamper), the web app I am trying to modify appears to be some kind of MVC which means I cannot see some of the data unless I am monitoring the traffic (cannot just inspect element).

I am using Kali Linux, I do also have a windows machine which has hackfox on it but sadly this is an alpha build and it does not function with the hackfox application.

currently using webscarab to monitor the traffic.

Answer (score 3):

You're so very close to the name of the Firefox/Iceweasel plugin you need with your question title!

Tamperdata: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tamper-data/

You could also use one of the Web proxies shipped with Kali, OWASP-ZAP or Burp Suite. You may want to gloss over the manuals for these, but in general you start them up, aim your Firefox/Iceweasel connection at their listening port (typically 127.0.0.1 : 8080) and then they can intercept your traffic and allow you to change post data before it fires.

Comment: BRILLO PADS! Thanks for that I will give it a whirl! was so close to my own answer it hurts :P

Comment: Plugin does not work correctly for AJAX requests though.

Comment: Modifying AJAX is very tricky